Matrix multiplications with SVD
I'm trying to understand the calculation of $SU = U(\sigma^2 I + D^2)$, which I need to prove with the condition $S(\sigma^2 I + WW^\top)^{-1}W = W$. Let $W \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}$ and $W = UDV^\top$ is the singular value decomposition of $W$, where $U \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}$, $D \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ (diagonal), and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. According to a source I found, the calculation proceeds as follows:
$SUD(D^2+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}V^\top = UDV^\top$
From there I know how to get to the result, but I don't quite get how they got to this step.
The source also mentioned that $\operatorname{tr}(WW^\top) = \operatorname{tr}(D^2)$, using the trace properties, I don't know if these to properties are related and if it would help to solve the above problem. Has someone an explanation how the transformation works and how or if these results are related?
Edit: I made a wrong assumption and changed the problem.

Because $D$ is diagonal so it commutes.

what is $W$?  It is not true in general that $WW^T$ is diagonal

Sorry guys, I made a false assumption.  I just assumed that $WW^\top = D^2$, which is of course not possible (dimensions don't fit). I edited now.

@Salcio Why would D commute? Could I for example say  $UDU^\top = (UD)U^\top = DU U^\top = D $ if the dimensions fit and $D$  is diagonal?

It is easy to check, take for $D$ a diagonal 2x2 matric and for $A$ any 2x2  matrix, Then compute $AD$ and $DA$.

Oh okay, but A needs to be symmetric to be true right?

Note that
$$
\sigma^2I_d + WW^\top = \sigma^2I_d + UD^2U^\top.
$$
For non-zero $\sigma$, RHS's eigenvalues are equal to the diagonal values of $D^2$ plus $\sigma^2$ so it's always invertible. Let $\widetilde{U} = [U,U_1] \in \mathbf{R}^{d \times d}$ be an orthonormal matrix such that $\widetilde{U}^\top \widetilde{U} = \widetilde{U} \widetilde{U}^\top = I_d$. Note that $U_1^\top U = U^\top U_1 = 0$ since their columns are orthogonal bases. Let $D = \operatorname{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_m) \in \mathbf{R}^{m \times m}$, and let $\tilde{D} = \operatorname{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_m, 0, \ldots, 0) \in \mathbf{R}^{d \times d}$. Then we have
\begin{align*} 
(\sigma^2 I + WW^\top)^{-1} &= (\sigma^2 I_d + UD^2U^\top)^{-1} \\
&= (\sigma^2 I_d + \widetilde{U}\tilde{D}^2\widetilde{U}^\top)^{-1} \\ 
&= (\sigma^2 \widetilde{U} \widetilde{U}^\top + \widetilde{U}\tilde{D}^2\widetilde{U}^\top)^{-1}\\
&= \widetilde{U} (\sigma^2I_d + \tilde{D}^2)^{-1}\widetilde{U}^\top \\ 
&= U(\sigma^2I_m + D^2)^{-1} U^\top + U_1 \sigma^{-2} I_{d-m} U_1^\top. 
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*} 
S(\sigma^2 I_d + WW^\top)^{-1} W &= S \left( U(\sigma^2I_m + D^2)^{-1} U^\top + U_1 \sigma^2 I_{d-m} U_1^\top \right) UDV^\top \\
&= SU(\sigma^2 I_m + D^2)^{-1}DV^\top. \\
\end{align*}
Then your conclusion follows.

Thanks for your answer. I have just a few questions: Where does the $U_1$ come from? And what does the $\tilde{U} = [U, U_1]$ mean? Sorry, I have never seen this before.

@Lopsio U's columns are orthonormal. We can always find remaining (d-m) unit vectors that are orthogonal to each other and orthogonal to U's columns. They together form the basis of the d-dimensional space. $\tilde{U}$ concatenates $U$ and $U_1$.

Ohh, thanks! One question remaining: If I pull out $\tilde{U}$ from the brackets shouldn't it be $\tilde{U}^{-1}$?

$\tilde{U}$ is orthonormal so $\tilde{U}^{-1} = \tilde{U}^\top$.

Yeah but if I pull out $\tilde{U}$ from the left side and $\tilde{U}^\top$ from the right shouldn't it be: $(\sigma^2\tilde{U} \tilde{U}^\top+\tilde{U} \tilde{D}^2\tilde{U}^\top)^{−1} = \tilde{U}^\top (\sigma^2 \tilde{U}^\top+ \tilde{D}^2)^{−1} \tilde{U}$, because of the exponent?

$(ABC)^{-1} = (BC)^{-1} A^{-1} = C^{-1} B^{-1} A^{-1}$.

Oh wow I am stupid. Thank you very much for your patience and help!
